# Definition of local absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, absolute-continuity

I am studying the notion of absolute continuity. I understood the definition of absolute continuity. I found many references where they use the notion of "local absolute continuity", but I did not find yet a definition of this concept.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: You should give some of the references for more context. For instance, there is [in some papers the notion of "points of absolute continuity"](https://zbmath.org/?au=&ti=%22points+of+absolute+continuity%22), but I suspect this is not what you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just checked the reference and you are right it is not the notion I am searching. But the reference you sent is useful for me because at least I understood that my intuition on what was local absolute continuity has the name of point of absolute continuity. Local a.c. is defined in the comment behind so everything is ok now!

Answer (score 1):

It's said a function is locally (refering to every bounded interval) absolutely continuous if and only if its distributional derivative is a measure that is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!